# drag and drop in primeface5.3

Tags: primefaces, drag-and-drop

I have two panels in left and right of page. I want to drag one input text from tab in left panel and drop it to right panel. My first issue is textbox can't be dragged and I don't know why. My second issue is when I drag element in left panel tab, tab is scrolled and I can't drop it to right panel.

My code is:

```
<p:panel id="mainPage" class="Row">
            <p:panel class="col-md-3" id="leftPanel" style="height:500px" header="Elements">
                <p:accordionPanel>
                    <p:tab title="Elements">
                        <div class="iscRow">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p:inputText id="input1">
                                </p:inputText>

                                <p:draggable for="input1"  />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p:graphicImage id="image1" name="images/excel.png" style="height: 50px;width: 50px"/>
      <p:draggable for="image1" containment="mainPage" />

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </p:tab>

                </p:accordionPanel>
            </p:panel>

            <p:panel class="col-md-9" id="rightPanel" header="page Design">

                <div class="iscRow">
                    <div id="headerDiv" class="col-md-12"  style="background-color: #EEEEEE;height: 200px;border-bottom: #adadad dashed;">


                            </div>

                        </div>                    



            </p:panel>

        </p:panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think your problem is accordian panel
>
> p:tab doesnt have scrollable property and because of its scroll
>   .element cant drag out of that tab.you can use two panel which can be
>   extended.